# Javascript problems: thisRate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput

Tags: javascript, html, validation, browser, undefined

I tried to design a very simple calculator to calculate the ratio based on invest amount. The error message is:

> thisRate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.oninput

Here is my code:

```
<!-- <form oninput="amout.value = (principal.valueAsNumber * rate.valueAsNumber) /100 " style = "font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"></form> -->

<fieldset>
    <legend>calculate</legend>

    <label for="principal">amout to invest:$</label>
    <input type="number" min="0" max="2000" id="principal" value="10000">

    <p><label for="rate">interest rate</label></p>
    <input id="rate" type="range" min="0" max="20" value="0" oninput="thisRate.value = rate.value">

    <output name="thisRate" for="rate">0</output><span>%</span>

    <p>
        interest received<strong>$<output name="amount">0</output></strong>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
var rate = document.getElementById("rate");
rate.oninput = ()=>{
 let value = rate.value; 
}
```

**Or**

```
 var rate = document.getElementById("rate");
    rate.onchange = ()=>{
     let value = rate.value; 
    }
```